# Passing index from html to js component

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

Looping through an array of objects.

```
    <template for:each={similarProducts} for:item="i" for:index="index">
      <div key={i.id} class="bx--col" data-field={field.type}>
        {productData}
      </div>
    </template>
```

Looking for a way to pass the index and type from the above for:each to the `productData` method

```
get productData() {
    return "hello";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`productData` is a getter, it can not take arguments. Instead of trying to get data there you will probably have to prepare a list of objects, with all properties you need, in advance and and loop over that.

Comment: Ok ... So is there any alternative to that getter? Something that can receive data from the html template?

Comment: No, in the template you can only use properties and getters. You can only read data from the template in a callback or normal function.
I might be able to help you further I you can explain what you're trying to achieve instead of how you try to solve your problem.